# How to Have the Same Code Execute to Two Different Consoles in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I recently found out that it is possible to have two consoles open in eclipse at the same time and I am wondering if it is possible to have a piece of code that prints different things to each of the consoles.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably be more specific. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i have two different eclipse consoles and I want to know if its possible to print to tone of them without printing to the other